# How to integrate amazon s3 securely using auth0 and react-native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, auth0

I've done some research into amazon s3 and am familiar with general terms such as IAM and temporary credentials. Still, I am struggling to design an effective strategy for s3 integration. I began down the path at https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/tokens but realized it is deprecated.

There are 2 types of users, managers and regular. My expo react native app currently uses auth0 for authentication to receive an id_token and an access_token. Managers are specified by the scope in the auth0 response.

Each manager user should be able to create multiple s3 folders and add other managers to them. Managers of a s3 folder should have full control in that folder. Folders and a list of their managers are stored in my mongo db.

1. What are the steps required to integrate s3 with users authenticated by auth0?
2. How can I adjust s3 security policies such that each manager can create folders and assign other managers to them?

UPDATE:
I was able to integrate auth0 with amazon cognito by following the instructions [here](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/integrating-auth0-amazon-cognito-mobile-apps). In summary these steps create a federated identity provider, namely auth0 and associate it with a cognito identity pool. The cognito identiy pool is amazon's recommended way of keeping track of users because using a custom identity pool requires you to call the

> AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity API to trade the authentication token you
>   get from those IdPs for AWS temporary security credentials.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html

But how do I customize the policy for the role associated with my cognito identify to use the claims from my auth0 id token?

I am using the following permission policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "myapp.auth0.com:http://myapp.com/scope": "write"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy displays the error

> This policy does not grant any permissions.

Why am I getting this error? Am I restricted to using the claims from cognito? If so, how can map auth0 specific claims into my cognito token?